# Maven - Simple plugin to zip jar files

Tags: java, maven

modules project.

```
 -1
  -pom.xml
 -2
  -pom.xml
 -3 
  -pom.xml
 -parent
  -pom.xml
```

and all modules inherit by a parent pom. What I have do is editing parent pom and I want to create a plugin to build zips with 2 jars (from -1 and -2)

I have tried something like that

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution> <id>createDistJar</id> 
                    <goals> <goal>run</goal> </goals>  <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="${project.build.directory}"/>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}"/>
                            <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/JawaBot-${project.version}-dist.zip"
                                basedir="target/" includes="JawaBot-${project.version}-dist-rh/**">
                            </zip>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>uploadDistJar</id> <goals>  <goal>attach-artifact</goal>  </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/JawaBot-${project.version}-dist.zip</file>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but it cretes zip for all modules within all /targer folder.

Comment: [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: can u give me example?

Comment: khmarbaise was faster than me. His answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

Make a separate module (xyz-dist) with a supplemental pom file which contains the dependencies of the modules you would like to make part of your distribution.

Add the dist module in your parent pom like the following:

```xml
  <modules>
      <module>dist</module>
      <module>package-1</module>
      <module>package-2</module>
  </modules>
```

In the `dist` module add the following to your pom:

```
<project...>

  <parent>
  </parent>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
      Dependencies of the modules you would like to package
  </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-bundles</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The `dist.xml` should contain the following:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>dist</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
          <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: so i need to add module to my parent pom.xml?  I every module i want to collect in zip add plugin maven-assembly-plugin and also create dist.xml in my parent folder?

Comment: Only add the dependency of the module in the dist pom and that's it...and only add the maven-assembly-plugin in the dist module nowhere else...

Comment: ok, Now i create zip but no with .jar files for my 1,2 module but with all depencances